# How do I include a single dependency in my JAR with Gradle?

Tags: java, jar, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm starting with Gradle and I was wondering how do I include a single dependency (TeamSpeak API in my case) into my JAR so that it could be available at the runtime.

Here is a part of my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Class-Path': '.......'
    }

    from {
        * What should I put here ? *
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.7.Final'
    compile group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.8-R0.1-RELEASE'
    // Many other dependencies, all available at runtime...

    // This one isn't. So I need to include it into my JAR :
    compile group: 'com.github.theholywaffle', name: 'teamspeak3-api', version: '+'

}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Dependencies are not stored inside a jar file. They are outside the jar file, and the Class-Path manifest entry contains the relative path to that jar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to start with a separate configuration for the dependencies you want to include. I know you only asked about a single jar but this solution will work if you add more dependencies to your new configuration. Maven has a well known name for this sort of thing called `provided`, so that is what we will use.

```
   configurations {
      provided
      // Make compile extend from our provided configuration so that things added to bundled end up on the compile classpath
      compile.extendsFrom(provided)
   }

   dependencies {
      provided group: 'org.spigotmc', name: 'spigot', version: '1.8-R0.1-RELEASE'
   }

   jar {
       // Include all of the jars from the bundled configuration in our jar
       from configurations.provided.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }
   }
```

Using `provided` as the name of the configuration is also important because when the jar gets published, any dependencies you have in the `provided`configuration will show up as `provided` in the POM.xml that gets published with the JAR. Maven dependency resolvers will not pull down `provided` dependencies and users of your jar will not end up with duplicate copies of classes on the classpath. See [Maven Dependency Scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Say I have two lists of dependencies: One to include in the jar and the other not include — how do I do it?


With the `maven-shade-plugin` compile was included and provided not. But in your example it seems the other way around.