# publishing a library - how to make it so that consuming app doesn't need to add repositories for transient dependencies

Tags: android, maven, gradle, pom.xml, maven-publish

I've created an Android library called `Library` and I want to publish it to a private maven repository and then consume it in an app called `App`.

I am encountering an issue however which is making the usage of the library untenable for `App`. The issue is that one of the dependencies of `Library` is hosted in a "non standard" maven repository, and is forcing the consuming `App` to add this repository to it's `repositories` block.

To explain this further; `Library` has lots of dependencies, most of which are pulled from `google` and `mavenCentral` repositories (both of which the consuming `App` has in the `repositories` block because all Android apps will include these repositories). However, one of the dependencies, `Quikkly`, is hosted in a "non standard" maven repository (i.e. one with a non standard URL), which also requires a github personal access token to access. So in my `Library` `repositories` block, I have to add this maven repo in order to pull this specific dependency:

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/quikkly/quikkly-android-sdk'
    credentials {
        username = <github_username>
        password = <github_access_token>
    }
}
```

All well and good; I can build `Library` just fine, and the `Quikkly` dependency is pulled successfully from this repository.

The issue arises when I use `Library` in `App`. I published `Library` to `mavenLocal` (or my own private maven repository depending on when I'm ready to actually push a release). When I pull `Library` into `App` and then build, the build fails because `Quikkly` could not be resolved.

The errors show that the locations searched were just the repositories defined in `App` and not those defined in `Library`. I can make the build succeed if I add the `Quikkly` custom maven repo (and github access token) to `App` but I don't want to force `App` developers to need to add custom repos just to use my library - surely my library should be responsible for properly packaging it's own dependencies such that consumers just need to use my library via a one line gradle import.

I've done some research on this, and I think the solution involves adding the custom maven repository URL to a `<server>` element in my libraries `.pom` file, however the repository also requires a github username and personal access token in order to pull the library from it... my research shows that I need to add these details to "somewhere" (but not in the `.pom` file as this would be insecure and/or wouldn't even work).

I'm now getting pressured to release something working, but I'm pretty stuck with this. Can anyone help?

Comment: publishing to Github Packages sucks badly ... do it old way: download aar and jar then add them from lib folder of your project

Comment: Grim, I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to that, feels yucky

Comment: Add Your private dependency with `api` instead of `implementation` via gradle in `dependencies` section. With that thing, You add whole library in another with sources. When You add `implementation`, You have to provide implenetation of Your library by Yourself.

Comment: Yea I think that could work KurdTt but then I'd be exposing this library to the consuming app which isn't ideal either is it... I don't want the consuming app to use this dependency, so `api` isn't really appropriate.

Comment: So, is what you're looking to do is have it declared as `implementation`, and to "fatten" the jar only a little, by only adding a SINGLE dependency into the final artifact?  If so, would something like this solve it for you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146204/how-do-i-include-a-single-dependency-in-my-jar-with-gradle  I believe these are your own two options..  Provide the repo, or provide the dependency inside.